# Cannot install ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04: Unmet Dependencies

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, packages, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have attempted the installation and always receive the error:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed

Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

When I try to install the unmet dependencies, I am met with even more unmet dependencies.

How do I proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195712/cannot-install-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04:-unmet-dependencies/) by [pdkoehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20560/pdkoehler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-23**:
What platform are you on? What repository are you using? What directions are you following?

**Comment by [Mellon](https://answers.ros.org/users/20851/mellon/) on 2014-11-18**:
I think there's some problem relating to i386 packages, since ros-indigo-simulators aparently asks for gazebo2:i386. I manage to reduce the unmet dependencies to ros-indigo-simulators allowing "main" repositories, then I managed to install the desktop version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu
1.4 Installation
Alternatively, try installing just this to fix dependency issues:
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic

This may be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [jingpang90](https://answers.ros.org/users/21945/jingpang90/) with karma: 16 on 2015-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UniversityStudent1701](https://answers.ros.org/users/29955/universitystudent1701/) on 2017-07-04**:
This solution is not working for me; I get the following error: `E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic`
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?